# When to use Command and RpcClient

Tags: unity, multiplayer, unity-networking

I'm working on a multiplayer turn-based project in unity 5.4 and Unity Networking. I'm trying to learn Networking and one thing I am wondering is when to use `[Command]` and `[RpcClient]`.

I know the difference between both :

- `Command` are executed by the server, and client are synced with it (I.E.: player X fired a bullet, send the command to the server, calculated the trajectory, and sync it with the clients).
- `RpcClient` are command sent to the client (I.E. Player died?)

When I write a function, what question do I need to ask myself to know if it's a Command or a Remote Procedure Call.

Comment: By the way you said it, use `Command` when it's a client action that requires a response from the server, like sending a `GET\POST` http request and expecting a result, and use `RpcClient` when it's an event that happens due to the update loop or whatever on the server, and the clients need to be modified, similar to a `PUT` http request.

Comment: Question:  Do I need to update the server on what a client did?  Command.  Do I need to update a client because of something that happened on the server?  RPC

Comment: I don't thinks that there can be some universal question, when you practice a bit you'll easily figure out what method does: let others know or listen to what others did

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Background

In normal client-server games, the server is *authoritative* meaning it has the final say over how the games state exists and is in charge of making sure the clients know the current game state. It does this by taking all of the game logic and running it instead of the clients* and then sending updates as it sees fit. The most basic building blocks of these mechanics are the `[Command]`, `[ClientRpc]`, and `[TargetRpc]` attributes. These aren't super high level like the automatic syncing stuff like `[SyncVar]` and `NetworkTransforms` nor are they super low level like sockets.

*<sub>It does this to the extent possible by which to not introduce too much network bandwidth (causing poor performance) and complexity. So usually the client is responsible for simulating and predicting physics, lighting, and other intensive tasks while the server just syncs object state, positions, and provides game notifications for playing client-side sounds and changing the UI.</sub>

#### How they differ

- [[Command](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.CommandAttribute.html)] - The `[Command]` attribute is called by a client (!) and executed by the server on that same object. The client can only call this on objects it has authority over. These usually relay some sort of client intent like fire my gun or send a chat message. Ignoring all the automatic syncing (`SyncVars`, `NetworkTransform`, etc) this is the only way for the client to do something on the server and as such all client network actions that have the chance to change the game or affect other clients need to be a `[Command]` that the client can call to run on the server.
- [[ClientRpc](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.ClientRpcAttribute.html)] - The `[ClientRpc]` attribute is called on the server and executed on **all** of the clients that are currently connected to the server for a given object. `[ClientRpc]` is most commonly used to notify the clients of game changes like a change in score or that they have died (to play sound and death animations on all players' screens).
- [[TargetRpc](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.TargetRpcAttribute.html)] - **Added in Unity 5.4** - The `[TargetRpc]` attribute is the same as above but is only executed on a **specific** client when called on the server. The server passes a `NetworkConnection` object to denote which client it would like to execute the `TargetRpc` on.

A super helpful overview of all this (including a nifty diagram) can be found [in the UNET tutorial series](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetActions.html).

#### When server authority matters

What I described above is the most common uses for these type of commands where server authority is very important (like competitive games). More casual games where cheating isn't a huge deal (coop games, games where you trust the other players to not cheat) might be structured differently.

An example might be a game where you fire a gun to shoot an enemy. In a non-competitive game where cheating isn't an issue, I might have a `ShotObject` command which clients call with the objects they shot. This is really easy to cheat but low complexity. In a competitive multiplayer game however, I would need have a `FireGun` command that takes no arguments and simulates the Raycast for the gunshot on the server alone so clients couldn't cheat. This introduces the added complexity of backing up the server simulation to when the client shot, doing the raycast, and then proceeding with the game.

The basic rule here is that when server authority matters, run as much as you can on the server. When it doesn't you're free to do what you want.

Comment: For future users:

Simple different is

**[Command][1] :** Client to Server

**[RPC][2]:** Server to Client


  [1]: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.CommandAttribute.html
  [2]: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetActions.html